# what will be atan2 output for both x and y as 0

Tags: c, undefined, trigonometry, angle, atan2

```
theta=atan2(0,0);
```

The output of this statement is 0, but it is a 0/0 form , so how its output can be 0, even wikipedia says that it should be undefined , please explain why compiler gives 0 as output for this statement.

Comment: The C standard says that `atan2(0, 0)` is a *domain error*, which leads to an implementation-defined return value.

Comment: Strictly, the standard says "A domain error may occur if
both arguments are zero."  The net result is much the same.  The standard also details what is supposed to happen in section §7.12.1 Treatment of Error Conditions.

Comment: Are you asking what kind of behaviour to expect when the behaviour is undefined..?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> what will be atan2 output for both x and y as 0

C has 2 relevant specifications. [@Oliver Charlesworth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47909048/what-will-be-atan2-output-for-both-x-and-y-as-0/47909231#comment82785497_47909048) [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47909048/what-will-be-atan2-output-for-both-x-and-y-as-0/47909231#comment82785793_47909048)

> **The atan2 functions** ... A domain error may occur if both arguments are zero. C11dr §7.12.4.4 2
>
> **Treatment of error conditions**   ...For all functions, a domain error occurs if an input argument is outside the domain over which the mathematical function is defined. ...; On a
> domain error, the function **returns an implementation-defined** value;...  §7.12.1 3

`atan2(0,0)` may lead to `0.0, 1.0, INF, NAN`, etc.  It is not specified other than something is returned.

`0.0` is certainly a reasonable choice yet there is no clear mathematically correct result - it is not defined.

---

For compatibility with [IEC-60559](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO%2FIEC%2FIEEE_60559?redirect=no) (which is not required by C although many implementation strive to adhere),  the following results are mandated.  Note the differences due to  ±0.

```
atan2(±0, −0) returns ±π
atan2(±0, +0) returns ±0.
```

A note on [π](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi).  π being an irrational number and all finite `double` are rational,  a return value of *machine pi* (the closest representable `double` to π) is expected with `atan2(+0, -0)`.

---

**Shorter version**

> "what will be atan2 output for both x and y as 0"

Zero.

> "how its output can be 0, even wikipedia says that it should be undefined"

Wikipedia  does not define C nor various math library specifications - it is a reference - not a specification.

> "why compiler gives 0"

That is the specified response from the floating point standard IEC-60559/[IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) often used by various C implementations.

Comment: Note also that the standard *mandates* this value if IEC-60559 compatible (see Annex F).

Comment: Can u please explain in some simple way , I cant properly get what you said 

Comment: @user9121710 Shorten answers appended.